# Problem with Send Mail IIS System.Net.Mail Namespace Visual Basic visual-studio-2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, namespaces, system.net.mail

I downloaded the “Send Mail” VB10 sample from the Visual Basic 2010 Samples web pang and installed IIS (Internet Information Services 5.1) on my Windows XP Pro SP3 laptop.  I was able to use the send mail sample instantly and went on to develop a more tailored program for sending mail.  It all works great!  However, when I take my laptop to different wifi network, with a different ISP (AT&T), something changes.  My program still “seems” to work – it even gives me the “Mail Sent Successfully” message, but no mail makes it to it’s destination.  Upon further investigation, I found that the outbound mail messages were accumulating in a folder called C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue.

What is causing this?  Can I reconfigure something on IIS or within my VB10 program to make it work on AT&T?  I have tried dozens of suggestions, but nothing has worked.  I developed my program for the purpose of using it on the AT&T network – I need to have automated messages sent to me from that (AT&T) location.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup IIS to forward the emails to your ISP so they can go out to the wide world.

Perhaps [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230235) KB article can help.

Also, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/48755/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-server-to-relay-outgoing-messages-to-another-local-smtp) ServerFault thread.